# error 10471 ReturnUrl is invalid

Tags: asp.net, paypal

This has been working well until a couple weeks ago. Now I receive a response back that the "ReturnUrl" is invalid. It is not the "ReturnURl=" but somewhere  in the whole of the url itself. 
I am sending for a return token, in order to authorize.
Any guidance appreciated.

Using ASP

```
Set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.open "post", GatewayHost, False
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/namevalue"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Host", "corp.ebay.com"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-VPS-Timeout", "30"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-VPS-VIT-Client-Architecture", "x86"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-VPS-VIT-Client-Certification-Id", "14"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-VPS-VIT-Client-Type", "ASP/Classic"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-VPS-VIT-Client-Version", "0.0.1"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-VPS-VIT-Integration-Product", "Homegrown"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-VPS-VIT-Integration-Version", "0.0.1"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-VPS-VIT-OS-Name", "windows"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-VPS-VIT-OS-Version", "2002_SP2"
parmList = "PWD[8]=" & PassWord
parmList = parmList + "&USER[9]=" & UserID
parmList = parmList + "&VENDOR[9]=" & VendorID
parmList = parmList + "&PARTNER[3]=" & PartnerID
parmList = parmList + "&TRXTYPE[1]=A" 
parmList = parmList + "&ACTION[1]=S"
parmList = parmList + "&TENDER[1]=P" 
parmList = parmList + "&AMT="  & session("cctotal")
parmList = parmList + "&RETURNURL=HTTPS://WWW.XXXXXXXXX.COM/XXXXXX.ASP"
parmList = parmList + "&CANCELURL=HTTPS://WWW.XXXXXXX.COM/XXXXX.ASP"
objXMLHTTP.send parmList
```

Comment: Could you provide the full response that you're getting?

Comment: RETURNURL - Character length and limitations: 2048 single-byte characters.
Are you passing a return URL that is within bounds?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that.

RESULT=7&RESPMSG=Field format error: 10471-ReturnURL is invalid.

Comment: In working with PayPal the resolution is, you cannot have the 'HTTPS' in caps in the returnurl or cancelurl.                                                                    This had been acceptable. Something must have changed around July 7th to make it not.  thanks for the replies.